# Experience Editor Preview Mode: The layout for the requested document was not found

Tags: experience-editor

When I try to show the preview mode in my Experience Editor I get the Message

"The layout for the requested document was not found"

[image]

It was already working and I don't know what I have done that this does not work any more.

The Final and shared Layout look the same

[image]

The default Layout looks good too.

[image]

I can't find any problems and don't know what to do to solve this issue

The Strange behavior is, that when I publish the page it works I get no error but the preview mode is not working

Comment: Edit mode of Experience Editor works correctly, right? What is the difference in the url between Edit and Preview modes?

Comment: Go to Navigate - > Links and confirm that default layout is referred by that particular item. Confirm that Default.cshtml is there in your website root folder.

Comment: @MarekMusielak yes the edit mode works fine. I can't see the preview Mode url because it show directly the layout not found page the current edit URL is: http://sitecore.local/?sc_mode=edit and when I change the edit into preview I see the error page

Comment: @siddharth Sorry I don't know what you mean with "Go to Navigate -> Links ..." Where can I find this? And yes the default.cshtml lies in on the website root in the corresponding folder

Comment: Open developer tools in Chrome (or whichever browser you use), and in the network tab check Preserve Logs. See what was the url that was redirected to LNF page

Comment: @MarekMusielak I think you mean this url: sitecore.local/?sc_mode=preview&sc_debug=0&sc_trace=0&sc_prof=0&sc_ri=0&sc_rb=0

Comment: Could this be a language issue? Are you trying to edit/preview the page in a language other than "en"?

Comment: @DanSinclair Yes it seems to be also a problem in this direction, its hard to really understand to give a 100% answer about the right solution :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working again. But I am not really shure how I solved this problem.

I've Reseted the Presentation Details für every shared and final Layout of the page and then I created a new Version for en and de-de. After that it works again.

Comment: Did it previously have both `en` and `de-de` versions? If so, did they both have layout defined (or do you have language fallback configured)?

Comment: @DanSinclair yes it should have a en and de-de versions but I am not shure. And I am a bit new to sitecore development I don't know how to configute language fallback

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Sitecore you're using, but there is good documentation for configuring language fallback: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/language-fallback.html